# How to play videos from url in Avplayer when a cell is tapped using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, video, swift3

I m trying to play videos from url in UITableViewCell with AVPlayer. I mean I want videos to play when a VideoTableviewCell which has an image for videos introduction and Label:title for that videos. When that image of video tapped on cell then that video from url will play in Avplayer controller. 
My problem is i am not able to get which cell image is tapped and how to play corresponding video url in another ViewController(AVplayerViewController). 
Can anyone help me to understand what to use to recognize  and connect which image is tapped and how to play video in another viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 4.2**

You need to implement **didSelectRowAt** and **AVKit**

First you need to import AV Kit

```
import AVKit
```

Next, get url from index cell in didSelectRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if let url = URL(string: yourArrayURL[indexPath.row]) {
      let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
      let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
      playerViewController.player = player
      present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
         player.play()
      }
   }
}
```

In my case it's work, I hope it's work for you too

Answer (score 1):

Implement

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

then inside this:

```
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? VideoTableviewCell {
        // cell.AVplayer.play
    }
```

This is a built in UITableView method to tell you when an individual cell is tapped.

Comment: This worked worked for me in the CollectionCell too. Thanks. Is there a way to stop the video to play on a second tap?